# Como listar dados de uma tabela, mesmo a outra (INNER JOIN) estando vazia?

Tags: codeigniter

Na minha página `index`, possuo um `input` de pesquisa para o usuário buscar os dados no banco, esse `input` chama esse método no `Controller`:

```
public function pesquisar() 
{     
        $this->load->model('Processo_model', 'processo');
        $dados['processo'] = $this->processo->get_processos_like();
        if (!$this->processo->get_processos_like()) 
        {          
            $this->load->view('/listar/listar_processo', $dados);
        } else {
            redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
        }
}
```

No model está assim o código do método:

```
function get_processos_like() 
{
        $termo = $this->input->post('pesquisar');
        $this->db->join('andamento', 'fkcodprocesso=codprocesso', 'inner');
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('nprocesso', $termo);
        return $this->db->get('processo')->result();
}
```

E na view, está assim:

```
<?php foreach ($processo as $proc) { ?>
<table>
<tr class="row">                                
<td><?= $proc->dtandamento; ?></td>
<td><?= $proc->descricao; ?></td>
</tr> 
<?php } ?>                    
</table>
```

O que acontece, é que quando o processo (da tabela Processos) ainda não possui andamentos (da tabela Andamentos), a busca me retorna null, ou não me retorna nada. Gostaria que exibisse os dados do processo mesmo ele não tendo nenhum andamento cadastrado.

Já tentei usar o `LEFT JOIN` mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lugar do `inner` no última parâmetro do método `$this->db->join` coloque `left`, exemplo:

```
function get_processos_like() 
{
        $termo = $this->input->post('pesquisar');
        $this->db->join('andamento', 'fkcodprocesso=codprocesso', 'left');
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('nprocesso', $termo);
        return $this->db->get('processo')->result();
}
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#CI_DB_query_builder::join)
- [CodeIgniter Left Join Query Example](https://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2016/07/codeigniter-left-join-query-example.html)
- [How to JOIN Tables in Codeigniter](https://arjunphp.com/how-to-join-tables-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: Dessa forma os dados do processo aparecem, mas dá problema no meu Modal de Add Andamento que tem dentro da view do Processo, entendeu?

Comment: @Ramiro você pediu uma coisa na pergunta, o que acontece no formulário é outro consequencia da mudança, para trazer dados da tabela da esquerda é assim que faz, e isso que foi estipulado na pergunta, mas, qual o problema que acontece agora?

Comment: O Modal até adiciona o andamento no banco, mas seta a fkcodprocesso com o valor '0'; ...ou seja, ele perde a referência do $id do processo, não sei por que.

Comment: @Ramiro ai você concordo que é outro problema, e não é o que está na pergunta? veja nós aqui ajudamos aquilo que está na pergunta e só ratificando trazer dados da tabela da esquerda e se tem algo na tabela da direita é assim que faz, o problema de perder a `$id` tem que olhar o que está carregando na sua `view`!

Comment: Ok, obrigado, vou marcar como aceita, mas se puder me ajudar com mais esse detalhe eu agradeço.

Comment: a view do modal está assim:   

<form action="<?= base_url() ?>andamento/cadastrar" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" id="fkcodprocesso" name="fkcodprocesso" value="<?= $processo[0]->fkcodprocesso; ?>">

Comment: @Ramiro leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help